# How to write sql statement for following scenario?

Tags: mysql, table

So I currently have an sql statement:

```
Select room_no, category from help_desk where room_no = '133' OR room_no = '120';
```

and it returns:

[image]

How would I write an sql statement that would return it like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use three things

- GROUP BY
- GROUP_CONCAT
- DISTINCT within GROUP_CONCAT

Here is such a query

```
Select room_no, group_concat(distinct category) categories
from help_desk where room_no in (133,120) group by room_no;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the group_concat feature.

[Group Concat](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

For example:

```
SELECT room_no, GROUP_CONCAT(category)  
FROM help_desk 
GROUP BY room_no;
```

Comment: How do I make sure they don't repeat (All unique categories).

Comment: you can combine with distinct in the group_concat :)